# Ensure dot.net site always runs

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've created a very small monitor web-app, which periodically polls other websites to check if they're alive. If they're not I'm sent an e-mail so I can react (e.g. if the site responds 503)

However my problem is that the monitor web-app is shutdown when the AppPool recycles, and it's never started again because it gets no requests.

Is there a way to ensure it'll start again after a recycle, restart of the server or similar ?

Currently it starts a background thread in global.asax Application_Start, and the thread is then in charge of keeping the monitor web-app alive, by polling it as well as the other sites.

This way it'll get a HTTP request every so often. However this obviously only works for keeping it alive, when it has actually been started.

I've read a bit about IIS Warm Up modules, however the site is hosted on a server I've no influence on, so that's not possible.

The site is built using ASP.Net 4.0 and it runs on an IIS 7.5 server.

Hope you have an idea :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [uptime robot](http://www.uptimerobot.com/) to ensure my application is always spun up. The beauty of this system is it only asks for the headers of a page on your website and gets status codes like "200-ok", "404-not found", etc. every 5 minutes. This means that uptime robot does not add noise to Google Analytics as the page is never requested.

Seems to work like a dream for me and its FREE for upto 50 sites!

Comment: Very neat site, I'll have to choose between this and pingdom. Will let you know what I end up with.

Comment: I've settled on uptime robot - It seems quite a nice deal as it's free for 50 sites :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should implement this as a windows service or console app run via a scheduled task.  A web site is really not the appropriate type of application.

Comment: Whilst that is true, I have no server running 24/7 which I can install a service / console app on. In other words I have no choice but using a web app. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I Agree with tvanfosson but if you need it right now, you can still configure the application pool not to recycle.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Nice detail, though I'm afraid I still have restarts etc. to worry about. Still it's great to know how to configure this.

Comment: I'am afraid you don't have any option other than Service and schedules console app then...

Answer (score 1):

It's better to make this up as a windows service or a scheduled console application. If you want to keep it as a webapplication then you can have 3rd party send pings to your application to keep it running. At my current client this is done with http://www.pingdom.com/ but there are other alternatives to it.

Comment: Good point using pingdom - We actually use that tool at work, I'd just completely forgotten about it.

Comment: Most of the time this approach, like in your current situation, is the easiest and cheapest to go for in the near end. I'm still in favor of turning it into a windows service.